# Is there a word which actually means the common incorrect usage of the word "reactionary?"

Tags: meaning, synonyms, malapropisms

People often use the word "reactionary" to mean: "quick to react or jump to conclusions based on scant evidence."

For example:

> People who think that this athlete is over the hill based on a single poor performance are simply being reactionary.

Of course, the word "reactionary" does not actually mean this. But is there a word which *does* have this meaning and could be used instead?

Comment: 'Impetuous' and 'over-hasty' are hypernyms; I'll check to see if any dictionary specifies 'quick to react or jump to conclusions based on scant evidence'.

Comment: Reactive, oppositional?

Comment: Is reactionary really widely used in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question comes with the tag, malapropism.

In also this sense, overreactive.  Or, to liken the start of word, reactionary, to rash, and reckless.

> **Overreactive** (adj): Too reactive; tending to overreact.

[[Wordnik]](https://www.wordnik.com/words/overreactive)

Comment: Yes, this seems to be the best-fitting word that can be directly substituted into the example I gave and it will still retain its same meaning.

Answer (score 3):

At [WinEveryGame](https://www.wineverygame.com/words/impetuous.html) there is a narrowed definition of **impetuous** that fits, but I'll add the broader dictionary definitions they give:

> *Impetuous* is an adjective which describes a person or a thing, usually an action or idea, as arriving at an outcome impulsively or
> without much critical thought.

........

> *impetuous* [adjective]
>
> - Acting or deciding upon something with little to no forethought
> - Aggressive or instantaneous in nature

..........................................

Colloquially, they

**shoot from the hip**.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/shoot_from_the_hip) [US Dictionary]:

> *shoot from the hip* [phrase] [informal]
>
> react suddenly or without careful consideration of one's words or
> actions.
>
> - *In the book he shoots from the hip and rides roughshod over reputations, holding a modicum of his once monumental power and
>   relishing it.*
> - *To some he is difficult to take seriously, and he may come across as the sort who shoots from the hip with little thought for the
>   consequences.*
> - *I know that she shoots from the hip and is liable to provoke righteous indignation.*
> - *He doesn't shoot from the hip but takes a more considered approach and would rather explain to people why he holds the views he holds
>   than intimidate them to his point of view.*

Answer (score 0):

I haven't encountered this kind of improper use of *reactionary* before, and while there's no very good single-word replacement that's also an adjective, there's a phrase that means exactly that: *to jump to conclusions*

> People who think that this athlete is over the hill based on a single poor performance are just jumping to conclusions.